# Why does this Python function not require an argument when it itself is being used as an argument?

Tags: python, function, class

I'm looking at a function that acts as a class factory and takes a function as an argument:

```
def Example(func):

    class Example(object):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self._name = name
    
    return Example
```

There is also another separate function:

```
def other_function(flags):
    flagvals = np.unique(flags)
    return {val: flags == val for val in flagvals}
```

I then see the first function being used with the second function as an argument:

```
my_example = Example(other_function)
```

Can anyone explain why `other_function` doesn't seem to require an argument itself here when it seemed to require one when it was defined?

Comment: `my_example = Example(other_function)` You are passing the function itself, not calling it. Why should any arguments be passed?

Comment: Because you are not invoking it here. You will need an argument when you do `func(flags)`.

Comment: Apart from the explanation above by Fractalism, we can't offer any more insights as you posted some random unclear code. The `Example` function never uses the argument `func` and it is also not clear what `Selection` is...

Answer (score 1):

Think about the types carefully. `other_function` is of type `function`, whereas `other_function(flags)` executes the function, passing the arguament, returning type `dict`. Therefore, when you pass `other_function` to example, you are passing the function itself, rather than the return value when the function executes. Because you are passing the function, rather than executing the function, you don't need to pass the arguament

Answer (score 0):

You just pass the function `other_function` to the function `Example` as a function parameter.

If you want to call `other_function` you can call it inside the `Example` function like this:

```
def Example(func):
    my_flags = ...
    func(my_flags)
    
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a simple example, I have modified the Example function:

```
def Example(func):
    return func

def other_function(flags):
    flagvals = np.unique(flags)
    return {val: flags == val for val in flagvals}
```

Now, if you pass argument, you will get a dictionary as `other_function` is returning a `dictionary`.

```
print(Example(other_function(5)))
#{5: True}
```

If you do not pass argument in `other_function` you will get a `function`:

```
print(Example(other_function))
<function __main__.other_function(flags)>
```